# visual studio build doesn't reflect code changes for ionic project

Tags: visual-studio, ionic-framework, ripple

I am working on an ionic project in VS. When I try to run the program on Ripple or mobile device itself by pressing play button (that contains all ripple, vs emulator and etc) I don't see changes made in my code. 
So, I think even though build log shows a successful build, it's not that successful. How can I fix that?
I see all changes when I use ionic CLI (ionic serve command) alternatively. But I want to use VS for the whole development job.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify which versions of VS and ionic you are using.
For me the issue was that the "watch" npm task didn't automatically start. So it was just enough to open View -> Other windows -> Task Runner Explorer and run the watch task. After that all the changes in code were automatically loaded in the emulator.
I use VS 2017, Cordova 6.3.1 and ionic 2